# Generate binary image of individual contours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to segment the football field. I have found the largest contour that represents the field area. I need to generate a binary image using that area.

I'm Following a research paper and followed all the steps including

1. Convert to HSV
2. Capture the H channel
3. Generate Histogram
4. Some processing (Not mentioning as irrelevant to the question)
5. Find the largest blob in the binary image

I have done it using Contours and I have the largest contour which represents the field area.

[image]

I need to use this specific contour to generate a new binary image which will contain only the area of this contour.

```
# Find Largest Blob
# mask is the processed binary image
# using that mask I find the contours and draw them on original 
#image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
largest_blob = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(image, largest_blob, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Comment: What about using `cv2.BoundingRect()` for finding ROI in images and save ROI using `cv2.imwrite()`?

Comment: @xanjay I'm not interested to store the ROI. I just wanna generate a binary mask that will contain the area of the `largest_blob` contour

Comment: It seems to me you have already done this. Just draw the contours on `image` as binary i.e, `cv2.drawContours(image, largest_blob, -1, 255, 2)` where `image` is of type `uint8`

Comment: I have to agree with @gilad. What do you want that `drawContours` doesn't give you?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using the `cv2.fillPoly(noiseless_mask, [largest_blob], 255)` function. Where `noiseless_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may do this, first find the bounding rectangle for those contours,

[image]

The bounding rectangle is indicated by the green box

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
```

Then use these to crop the image

```
field = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
```

Then you may apply binarization to the `field` object, more info can be found here
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: I don't wanna crop the image. I just wanna grab the largest contour (which i have in the largest_blob variable) and i wanna make a binary image of it.

I'm looking for something like

    `binary_image = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))`

and then something i want to make all the pixels white in the given contour